# Is there anyway to run iOS or Android code on a desktop application?

Tags: android, ios, electron, dji-sdk

I would like to use an iOS or Android SDK (e.g. `DJI Drone SDK`), but instead of running it on a mobile device to connect to the hardware, is there a way to build a desktop application (e.g. `Electron` based) and be able to run their SDK to interact with the hardware?

Comment: It is not possible to Embed Android SDKs inside of a NodeJS desktop app.. If the SDK isn't Android dependent and instead just a pure Java jar, then you can load it via JNI. Otherwise you are out of luck. This is a classic problem of web developers trying to use Javascript and HTML and stuff for a System application. If the iOS code can be compiled for OSX, then it will work.. but not with NodeJS. You'd have to code in Objective-C, C++, C, or Swift.

Answer (score 0):

On **Windows** you can use **Android** **Studio** for run apps to **Android** .APK
Download it now https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
Don't forget you need to know Java language to using Android Studio you can learn watch some tutorials on Youtube

On Mac you need to use Xcode 
You can't run **IOS** Mac apps on Windows you can it with Virtual Machine like Vmware.
It's **Xcode** for download
https://developer.apple.com/xcode/
Don't forget you need to know Swift language to make an app on Mac for Mac and IOS

Comment: If that's the case, is there a way to run iOS code inside of Electron to be used as a desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

It is called DJI Assistant 2 but you still need your controller:
https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-testing.html

Answer (score 0):

https://waydro.id let's you do this on Linux.

For Windows, there's https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/10/20/introducing-android-apps-on-windows-11-to-windows-insiders/ for ~2 years now. See also https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/11ptn4e/comment/jc4oq97/ which links to https://github.com/cinit/WSAPatch

For macOS and other platforms you'll have to use an Android emulator.